# Why my private IP is not within the allowed ranges?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ip, vagrant

My Vagrantfile

```
 config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "172.16.0.22"
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", 2]
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 2048]
      v.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--nicpromisc1', 'allow-all']
```

After vagrant up

```
The IP address configured for the host-only network is not within the
allowed ranges. Please update the address used to be within the allowed
ranges and run the command again.

  Address: 172.16.0.22
  Ranges: 10.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0.0/16, 2001::/64
```

As I understand 172.16.x.x are private IPs.My wlo1

```
wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:94:32:93:05:p2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp3s0
    inet 192.168.1.19/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
       valid_lft 3068sec preferred_lft 3068sec
```

I changed network.conf file,by adding 172.16.0.0
cat /etc/vbox/networks.conf

```
* 10.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/16 172.16.0.0
* 2001::/64
```

The same problem is still here.

Why is IP outside of the network range?

Comment: You forgot the prefix length in the conf. `/12` (or maybe longer; depends on what you really want).

Comment: @TomYan Yeah,I got it.

Comment: @TomYan, Though brief, your comment really *is* an answer. You might expand just a bit (e.g., showing syntax), to make it complete, to help others with that issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as per the OP, apparently vagrant determines which IP subnet block(s) can be used for host-only network based on the file `/etc/vbox/networks.conf`.

An IP subnet is only valid if comes with a subnet mask or prefix length (which are essentially the same thing in different representations), as it indicates the size of the subnet. Address / subnet ID like `172.16.0.0` indicates only the "starting point" of a block or is otherwise considered a single, arbitrary host address.

Therefore, if you want to allow the whole `172.16.0.0/12` block as defind in the RFC, put that (whole thing) in the conf file. (Or, if necessary and/or desired, I'm pretty sure you can allow just part(s) of the block, as long as you have a valid subnet ID and prefix length combination. I'm not gonna tell the full story of subnetting 101 here.)